# Rails: How to fix "Missing secret_key_base for 'production' environment"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I simply can't get past the message:

```
Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit` (ArgumentError)
```

I have Rails 5.2.0, and ran

```
EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit
```

and inside:

```
production:
   secret_key_base: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Save and, in the terminal:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails c
```

Am I missing something? I've restarted the server and got the same issue, but have no issue in development mode.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Rails v4/5**

Keep default the `secrets.yml` file

```
# config/secrets.yml
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  aws_secret: abcde
  some_password: abcdex

development:
  secret_key_base: static_secret_key
  aws_secret: abcde

test:
  secret_key_base: static_test_secret_key


#not_indented: key for all env in once
secret_key_base: global_key_for_all_env
```

```
RAILS_ENV=production SECRET_KEY_BASE=production_test_key rails c
```

---

**Rails v5.2.0** add to production env below, check this [LINK](https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336)

```
config.require_master_key = true    #config/environments/production.rb
```

---

**Rails v7**
https://blog.assistancy.be/blog/how-to-store-credentials-in-rails-7/

Comment: Ensure that this secret file is inside `config` directory of your app.

Comment: This solution is the old way of doing things, Rails 5.2 has a better solution ("encrypted credentials").

Comment: The file name should be `secrets.yml`. By the way, this solution is not working for me.

Comment: @zmd94 make sure `.yml` file indents, This method not deprecated yet. Im running 3-5 projects in production `Rails <5.1` versions.

Comment: Alright, nevermind. I find another solution for this problem by adding `config.secret_key_base = 'YourSecretKeyHere'` in my `production.rb` located at `config/environments` folder. The 'YourSecretKeyHere' can be generated by run `bundle exec rake secret` command.

Comment: @zmd94 this was the ONLY thing that would help me. I tried every other solution on this page. This problem is completely ridiculous. Rails needs some kind of official solution.

Comment: Agreed. By the way, I'm no longer used `secrets.yml` in my project. Just migrate to use `credentials.yml`.

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: @AndrewKoster what's yr problem ? This question had been asked 2018 based on Rails4/5 versions.

Comment: There are correct answers here, also from 2018. Rails 5 came out in 2016. Your answer doesn't even specify that it's for Rails 4, which is very misleading.

Answer (score 37):

Rails 5.2.0 requires an extra stage for the production environment:

```
config.require_master_key = true    # in config/environments/production.rb
```

Without it, Rails still falls back to the legacy `secret.yml` mechanism (for now).

Engine Yard's Christopher Rigor [has written a concise post on it](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-rails-5.2). The relevant piece:

> #### Reading the Credentials
>
> If you want to use the credentials in the production environment, add the following to `config/environments/production.rb`
>
> ```
> config.require_master_key = true
> ```

A good read to also see up and down sides.

Note: As @TomDogg found out, Rails 5.2.1 seems again different, so this answer may only apply to 5.2.0.

Comment: No, `config.require_master_key = true` is not necessary (maybe it was necessary earlier). What is required now is `config.read_encrypted_secrets = true`

Comment: @TomDogg Is your comment related explictly to Rails 5.2 (the scope of the question) ? This answer is framed for 5.2, and backed by experience and the post from Rigor. It may not apply to other Rails version.

Comment: I have Rails 5.2.1 running in front of me. It does not have `config.require_master_key` anywhere, meaning my initial comment remains valid. (And the "Second:" part in my answer is crucial to make this work, you may try it out.)

Comment: Sorry for shortcut in the above comment. The question is about 5.2.0. I am using that version too. Good to know 5.2.1 is still different. Adding a tag to the question.

Comment: That's odd since Rails 5.2.2 definitely has `#config.require_master_key = true` in config/environments/production.rb.

Comment: The link is broken and Engine Yard's server isn't suggesting similar links. It appears to be [on Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20190208100100/https://www.engineyard.com/blog/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-rails-5.2) but is taking a long time to retrieve it.

Comment: @theTinMan I have just tried now, and the link worked fine. Any temporary issue between January and now, perhaps?

Comment: I'm using Rails 6 and this is still necessary. Only correct answer here.

Answer (score 7):

config/credentials.yml.enc:

```
development:
  some_username: XXXXXXXXX
  some_password: YYYYYYYYY

test:
  some_username: XXXXXXXXX
  some_password: YYYYYYYYY

production:
  some_username: XXXXXXXXX
  some_password: YYYYYYYYY

secret_key_base: ZZZZZZZZZ
# `secret_key_base:` must NOT be indented !
# It must be put at the very start of a new line.
# There is also no need for it in development or test environment,
#   since there are no attacks to be expected.
```

Also make sure that you respect all YAML indention rules (i.e. 2 spaces only) as failing to do so my make loading of this file fail silently.

Comment: @7urkm3n - Done, hombre.

Comment: @7urkm3n Well, this is simply following how Rails now handles credentials (with encryption). Of course you're free to think that the old way is better for some reason. If you're not sure, just read the relevant blog posts that explain the rationale behind it.

Answer (score 6):

Secret_key_base isn't properly setting.
It's a known issue not getting enough attention: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32947

Generate the keys with:

```
EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit
```

Record the key.
Save in `config/master.key`.

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE=`cat config/master.key` bin/rails assets:precompile
```

This is the solution I came to. I really don't like how I've been forced to put it though an environment variable. If someone has more information to bring to my attention on how master.key and such work, please do comment.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. It equals SECRET_KEY_BASE=dummy . "dummy" works very well in the Dockerfile with secrets.yml in the old fashion. Environment has real SECRET_KEY_BASE not accessible docker build time. Thx for direction.

Comment: Edit: I'll look back at this later.

Answer (score 5):

There are no `production:` `development:` and `test:` environment tags in the credentials file. Further information in this DHH's post: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/30067

So write directly

```
secret_key_base: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Please don't confuse master key with the secret key base. The master key is used to open the credentials encrypted file.

Switching back to the previous secrets system should not be the solution, nor the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, you **can** have a hierarchical structure in the credentials file, using keys such as for example `production:`, `development:` and `test:`.

Comment: I didn't say that you cannot have hierarchical structure, of course you can, read the whole post. With secrets if you have a key X under production: it accessed directly by Rails.application.secrets.X  Using credentials it should be something like Rails.application.credentials.dig(:production, :X). In 'secrets' the environment is automatically selected. If you use credentials is not advisable to use this categories, just use a different credentials file for each environment and forget about production, development or test. This case if use is similar to the .env file.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem when deploying my rails app to dokku using a Dockerfile. My solution:

the file `config/secrets.yml` references an environment variable:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

I need to set this variable using the dokku command line (either directly on the server, or using the dokku-cli gem on my development machine). Using dokku-cli I can do this remotely like so:

```
dokku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE=blalbalblablahblablah
```

or if I log into the server and run the dokku command there it's

```
dokku config:set myrailsapplication SECRET_KEY_BASE=blalbalblablahblablah
```

Comment: It should be `dokku config:set <appname> SECRET_KEY_BASE=blalbalblablahblablah`

Comment: ah, I use dokku-cli from my development machine, then I don't have to specify the application. it's read from the git remote dokku. I've added more details on this

Answer (score 3):

Avoid putting secret_key_base under environment tag. Put it above it.

This is wrong:

```
production:
   secret_key_base: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   some_other_key: xxx
```

Try this instead:

```
secret_key_base: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
production:
   some_other_key: xxx
```

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this same issue when working on a Rails 5.2 application in production.

I already had other things set up. The problem for me was not that the `secret_key_base` wasn't set properly, it was rather because of the **Passing the environment's name as a regular argument like below is deprecated**

```
rails c RAILS_ENV=production
```

If you look at your error log generated closely from its top you will see this:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing the environment's name as a regular argument is deprecated and will be removed in the next Rails version. Please, use the -e option instead. (called from  at bin/rails:9)

To run the rails console in a different environment, use the -e option like this:

```
rails console -e production
```

**Note**: Setting the `secret_key_base` in the `secrets.yml` file is not safe, as it's not a secure way of storing the key, please use the encrypted `credential.yml` file and the `master key` to decrypt it.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**