# i could not find secret.yml file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I could not fine the

```html
secret.yml
```

format in ruby on rails application I have created.
Can anyone help and tell me how to generate a new one.

Thank before hand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466887/missing-secret-key-base-for-production-environment/51467308#51467308

Comment: if file not exist, just create it yrself under `config/secrets.yml`

Comment: But rails <5 version is updated make sure that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### rails version 5.1

if your rails version 5.1, this command below will generate  2 files. 
config/secrets.yml.key contains the key that will encrypt and decrypt your secrets

```
bin/rails secrets:setup
```

After creating the key, even though config/secrets.yml.enc is not empty, 
it doesn't contain any secrets. To add your secrets, run

```
bin/rails secrets:edit
```

#### rails version 5.2

meanwhile if your Rails version 5.2, or above replaces both secrets with encrypted credentials. 
You cannot use plain text credentials. There's only credentials.yml.enc.
The encrypted credentials are saved on config/credentials.yml.enc. 
Don't edit the file directly. To add credentials, run

```
bin/rails credentials:edit
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have it generate it !!!

```
bundle exec rake secret
```

Update.

paste generated string to your config/secret.yml

```
development:
  secret_key_base: <key>
```

Comment: Using the command in terminal, I could only see list of string. There is no file generated in application.