# Deploying Rails App on Digital Ocean and when running cap production deploy:initial I get back ---> 01 ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Deploying Rails App on Digital Ocean and when running `cap production deploy:initial` I get back

> 01 ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit`

I thought that I've set it already:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["132efa1cdc31b591fa97e11450182f7ece21c9409451ea74e65974a9fad9e1d27846895afe0ffc4ee09d0d87912532a8d64e9a465e3cdf4455dee4ff3830"] %>
test:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["1113232efa1cdc31b591fa97e11450182f7ece21c9409451ea74e65974a9fad9e1d27846895afe0ffc4ee09d0d87912532a8d64e9a465e3cdf4455dee4ff3830"] %>
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["11173232efa1cdc31b591fa97e11450182f7ece21c9409451ea74e65974a9fad9e1d27846895afe0ffc4ee09d0d87912532a8d64e9a465e3cdf4455dee4ff3830"] %>
```

I am using the digital ocean rails one click with ubuntu sever

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing secret\_key\_base for 'production' environment,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466887/missing-secret-key-base-for-production-environment)

Comment: @oreoluwa is right, you have your environment name & value flip-flopped in your code snippet you shared.

Answer (score 2):

Usually your `secret_key_base` would be stored in an environment variable, however the secret key base isn't supposed to be the name of the env key.
In your case, that's what I seem to observe.

```
development:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["132efa1cdc31b591fa97e11450182f7ece21c9409451ea74e65974a9fad9e1d27846895afe0ffc4ee09d0d87912532a8d64e9a465e3cdf4455dee4ff3830"] %>

test:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["1113232efa1cdc31b591fa97e11450182f7ece21c9409451ea74e65974a9fad9e1d27846895afe0ffc4ee09d0d87912532a8d64e9a465e3cdf4455dee4ff3830"] %>

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["11173232efa1cdc31b591fa97e11450182f7ece21c9409451ea74e65974a9fad9e1d27846895afe0ffc4ee09d0d87912532a8d64e9a465e3cdf4455dee4ff3830"] %>
```

So, here's what I'd propose, instead of setting your secret as the key of your env variable, you'd probably just want to do something like:

```
secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Then, you'd want to set your environment variable in your digital ocean instance.

I've not used Capistrano before, but take a look at `default_env` in https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/
and [Capistrano and environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672631/capistrano-and-environment-variables)

In your case, I figured you'd probably want to do something along the lines of

```
set :default_env, { 
  'SECRET_KEY_BASE' => '11173232efa1cdc31b591fa97e11450182f7ece21c9409451ea74e65974a9fad9e1d27846895afe0ffc4ee09d0d87912532a8d64e9a465e3cdf4455dee4ff3830'
}
```

Let me know if that helps