# How to deploy using secret_key_base with VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, digital-ocean, vps

I tried to deploy my application on VPS but got an error:

```
ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit`
```

I added my `secret_key_base` to the environment variable:

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=<my secret key>
```

but am getting the same error.

secrets.production.yml:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Comment: Did you tried this solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180650/how-to-solve-error-missing-secret-key-base-for-production-environment-rai Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466887/missing-secret-key-base-for-production-environment

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails >=5.2, you should run this command:

```
rails credentials:edit
```

The  command will create the `config/master.key` and `config/credentials.yml.enc` files.