# could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a service that depends on a postgresql database but I can't figure out how to link the two together / connect.

I'm 'depending on' the database which seems to mean I should be able to use the service name as the database host name (i.e `due_database`) but whenever I do I just get the error:

`could not translate host name "due_database" to address: Name or service not known`

What's wrong here?

```
version: '3'
services:
  due:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/bot/Dockerfile
    command: ./due
    depends_on:
      - due_database
  due_database:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/database/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD="docker"
    entrypoint: /entry.sh
    volumes:
      - ./.dueutil_db:/dueutil_data
```

**Update**:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  due:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/bot/Dockerfile
    entrypoint: /entry.sh
    command: ./due
    depends_on:
      due_database:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - PGPASSWORD="docker"
  due_database:
    image: postgres:11
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD="docker"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - ./.dueutil_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I fixed the first issue by moving my create database scripts outside the postgres image, since that conflicts with the postgres entrypoint. 
However I still can't figure out how to connect to the database from my app's container.

I'm currently trying `psql -U postgres -h due_database postgres -f <sql script>` but I'm just getting:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "due_database" (172.18.0.2) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Note I did see: [psql: could not translate host name "somePostgres" to address: Name or service not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055882/psql-could-not-translate-host-name-somepostgres-to-address-name-or-service-n) but the question seems outdated & did not get any good answers.

Comment: What part of the system is trying to make the connection?  (In particular, is it something in your Dockerfile?)  That `docker-compose.yml` file looks pretty reasonable.

Comment: Please post output of docker network ls and docker network inspect of those networks listed. Also, check if due_database container didn't stop in meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my first issue was trying to make changes to the PostgreSQL image, copy some scripts in and add a custom entry point. That overrides the postgres startup script & means the database fails to load.

The second issue was using the non-alpine postgres image. Switching to `postgres:12.1-apline` 'just worked'. I'm not sure what's wrong with the other image though.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/), I'm not sure but maybe it can help you :

```
version: '3'
# ----------------
# CREATE NEW NETWORK
networks:
  app:
    driver: bridge
# ----------------
services:
  due:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/bot/Dockerfile
    command: ./due
    depends_on:
      - due_database
    # ---------------
    # SPECIFY NETWORK
    networks:
      - app
    # ---------------

  due_database:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/database/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD="docker"
    entrypoint: /entry.sh
    volumes:
      - ./.dueutil_db:/dueutil_data
    # ---------------
    # SPECIFY NETWORK
    networks:
      - app
    # ---------------
```